# How should we deal with questions about 5e rules from people playing Baldur's Gate 3?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic, dnd-5e, video-games

We have had several questions from people that play Baldur's Gate 3, and ask about how something that happens in the game works within the 5e tabletop rules.

For example:

- [Can a warlock be transformed into a devil for breaking their pact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208152/75095)
- [Animate Dead in BG3 has me wondering](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208237/animate-dead-in-bg3-has-me-wondering)

The second question is a good example that apparently the rules in the game work not exactly like the 5e rules (I haven't played the game yet, but based on the question, you can dispel zombies there).

Should we allow these questions, or should we close them and send them to the [ARQADE stack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)?

Related:
[Are all questions that are even tangentially related to Computer-Based RPGs or computer games off topic for this stack?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/are-all-questions-that-are-even-tangentially-related-to-computer-based-rpgs-or-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are all questions that are even tangentially related to Computer-Based RPGs or computer games off topic for this stack?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/are-all-questions-that-are-even-tangentially-related-to-computer-based-rpgs-or-c)

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate. The linked question is essentially asking the same thing here, and the answer there addresses your question here just fine, to the point that OSage’s answer below is a good tl;dr of that answer. So unless there’s a reason to *revisit* the discussion, it’s a suitable duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That's fine.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about that Q and A when I thanked you for opening the meta.  @ThomasMarkov Good Catch. 

Comment: "*The second question is a good example that apparently the rules in the game work not exactly like the 5e rules (I haven't played the game yet, but based on the question, you can dispel zombies there).*" There is no Dispel Magic spell in Baldur's Gate 3. Perhaps the question asker was really after that missing spell. As in "What would happen in regular D&D rules, as the video game does not offer the situation". Which would be *inspired by* a video game but a question about the tabletop game rules instead.

Answer (score 19):

#### Is the question *about* BG3 or *inspired by* BG3?

Questions about BG3's mechanics or (game-specific) lore belong on Arqade: they're not about a paper & pencil RPG, they're about a video game.

Questions about D&D 5e's rules or setting belong on RPG.SE: they're about a paper & pencil RPG, even if they were inspired by a video game.

Comment: And if it's not clear (enough) what they're asking about, just close the question as unclear and ask them to clarify. :)